# In Macvim with +python3 supported, which command should I use to execute the current file itself?

Tags: python, vim, macvim

I just set up IDE env for Python 3. I was wondering how I can run the file being currently edited in vim. I remembered that the command was ":python %", but it did not work for Python 3.

Thank you very much.

Comment: How exactly did it 'not work'?  Was there an error message?  It's easier to debug things with full information about what happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Python 3, just simply execute `:!python3 %`

---

Furthermore, you might also want to map it to a hotkey in your settings, like what I did:

`noremap <D-r> <esc>:w<CR>:!python3 %<CR>`

So that you can just press `Command+r` to execute the current code with Python 3 anytime (it will be saved automatically.

Comment: There is `nnoremap` for this kind of things: I bet you don’t know whether or not OP has, for example, done `noremap : ;|noremap ; :`.

Comment: @ZyX My advice is for the general case. If the OP had done `noremap : ;`, then I would bet that he does know that how to take my advice in right way.

Comment: Using `*noremap`, `normal!`, `feedkeys(, "n")` for *anything* you distribute and for *anything* you write in the vimrc unless you do know and do want at least part of the rhs to be remapped *is* a general advice. Yours is not: can you say what is expected to be remapped here?

Comment: Point taken. I think you are right. I will update it and thank you:-)

Answer (score 2):

you could use

```
:!python %
```

and it will surely work. Now your python should be pointing to python3 in this case, if not just write `:!python3 %` instead

Comment: Unless python points to python2 rather than python3.  Also, any reason for using the filename instead of `%`?  Shouldn't that work also?

Comment: when using `:!` in vim you are executing a bash command directly so if your `python` points to `python2` you can use `:!python3 your_file.py`. Also you can do any bash command using the `:!`approach. Just tested  `:!python %`and it does work, so I'll edit my answer